# Circular Object Detection from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

How to detect optical circles(hollow as well as filled)? Is there any approach which can solve segementation issue in generalize way?

I was not able to detect optical circle when I apply the following approach:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image= cv2.imread("cropped.jpg")

lower_bound = np.array([0,0,0]) 
upper_bound = np.array([255,255,195])

blur_factor = (3,3)
image= cv2.blur(image, blur_factor)

mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_bound, upper_bound)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
contours.sort(key=lambda x:cv2.boundingRect(x)[0]) 

array = []
ii = 1

for c in contours:
    (x,y),r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    r = int(r)
    if r >= 12 and r<=15:
        cv2.circle(image,center,r,(0,255,0),2)
        array.append(center)

for i in array:
    text_color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.putText(image, str(ii), i, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, text_color, 2)
    ii = ii + 1

cv2.imshow("masked",mask)
cv2.imshow("circled",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I'm gonna go ahead and suppose you wanna detect black circles on these images.
I'm not gonna delve into smoothing parameters, I don't think that's the issue here (not very blurry image, and easy to segment). Your code is fine for detecting components enclosed in a circle with a certain radius. You're getting a bunch of false positives because *an object enclosed in a circle is not necessarily a circle*.

Consider the two following pink objects : with your code, both of them are detected with an enclosing circle (in white) with the same radius
[image]

Since here we are lucky to try to detect full circle, an easily recognizable object, I would suggest to check for each circle you detect if the object inside it occupies a big part of this circle or not. This will enable to eliminate false positives such as the pink line in example above.

So with minimum tweaking of your code, I would suggest something like

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image= cv2.imread(your_image)

lower_bound = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_bound = np.array([255,255,195])

blur_factor = (3,3)
image= cv2.blur(image, blur_factor)

mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_bound, upper_bound)
maskg=np.copy(mask)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours=contours[1]

array = []
ii = 1

for c in contours:
    #for mask creation
    imgg=np.zeros(image.shape[0:2])

    (x,y),r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    r = int(r)
    if r >= 12 and r<=18:
        #potential interesting circle. Let's check if it's a full circle. Create a mask with only your full circle
        cv2.circle(imgg,center,r,255,-1)

        #mask your thresholded image by this mask
        masked=cv2.bitwise_and(maskg.astype(np.uint8),maskg.astype(np.uint8),mask=imgg.astype(np.uint8))

        #and count how much white pixels are in this mask (divided by the mask's area)
        circle_fullness=np.sum(masked)/(np.pi*r**2*255)

        #if more than X% of the area is indeed an object, than you've got yourself a full circle
        if circle_fullness>=0.8:
            #and then do you consider it as positive
            array.append(center)
            cv2.circle(image, center, r, (0, 255, 0), 2)

for i in array:
    text_color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.putText(image, str(ii), i, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, text_color, 2)
    ii = ii + 1

cv2.imshow("masked",mask)
cv2.imshow("circled",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result [deleted on demand]

Comment: The line you're quoting is creating an image with your original thresholded image masked by the considered min enclosing circle. Meaning a black image except for the area inside the min enclosing circle which will be your thresholded image. Try out the code and imshow() stuff :)
For your number identification problem, this is an entirely different problem : check out OCR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition, I think there are implementations in OpenCV.

Comment: That was your code, I just changed the numbers. The idea is to look for all min enclosing circles, and select only those which have a certain radius (between 12 and 18) because you know that's the kind of radius you're looking for.

Comment: You can take a look at Hough Circle transform

Comment: Hough Circle transform is sensitive to noise and accuracy is not good